# Bing Maps Development - Map with Markers

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, geospatial, bing-maps, virtual-earth

I really like how this site looks: http://www.microsoft.com/web/WebsiteSpark/Catalog.aspx - specifically the GIS part - the map, the green markers, and how the markers on the map our bound to the list below.  Would anyone know some resources on how I can get started on developing something like this?

This site is appealing and really like the markers.  For my application, I am seeking CRUD capabilities, that is, the ability to Create new points, Edit them, enter new data, and ability to Delete them.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very broad question, but these may be good places to start:

http://www.microsoft.com/mappoint/en-us/default.aspx

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?TagName=GIS&query=%22GIS%22

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helpful links.  Sorry for the confusion, but I have updated my initial post.  I am only interested in the mapping part.  Are you sure they are using Map Point?